# jQuery AJAX function throwing unknown error

Tags: jquery

I have the following function in a jQueryMobile page running in chrome and firefox. This same function runs without error in a PhoneGap + jQueryMobile app in iOS Simulator, but for some reason when it's run in the browser the error function gets called.

`textStatus` returns `null` and `errorThrown` returns `"error"`

```
$.ajax({type : "GET", 
        url : "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=356541460&entity=album", 
        data : {get_param : "results"}, 
        dataType : "json", 
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(errorThrown); alert(textStatus);}, 
        success : function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                $.each(this, function(index, element) {
                    if (element.wrapperType === "collection") {
                        $("#albums-list").append("<li><a id='albums-a-" + element.collectionId + "' href='#album-details'><img src='" + element.artworkUrl100 + "' />" + element.collectionName + "</a></li>"); 
                        $("#albums-a-" + element.collectionId).bind('click', function(index) {
                            Albums.AlbumID = element.collectionId;
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
            $("#albums-list").listview("refresh");
        }
});
```

Could this be a bug? Is this not designed to run in a browser?

Is there another function that I could use that would not have this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a cross domain request (likely), you need to add a callback for jsonp to the URL:

```
url : "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=356541460&entity=album&callback=?",
```

Comment: Wow... That doesn't make a lot of sense, but it works! Should I add this to my url in my PhoneGap app too? It seems to work without it, but if it's better to have, then I'm all for it.

Comment: @SnareChops I'm not sure whether iOS apps play by the same rules. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP